# MySQL Workbench - date_sub issue

Tags: mysql

when i type:

```
select date from table where date > date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL '7' day);
```

the system returns dates prior to 7 days.  For example today is jan 31, 2017 and yet i get a row with the date of jan 19, 2017.   That's more than 7 days.  Any reason why? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The query looks correct.  My only guess would be that the data in your `date` column has some problem.  Is it stored at `datetime` or some other type?

Comment: hi.  It's stored as datetime.  makes no sense huh

Comment: There must be some other problem with your data then.  Try creating a Fiddle and share the link with us if you can.

Comment: just to cover the basics, did you check what curdate() outputs?

Comment: yes, 
select curdate();  shows 2017-01-31.  Now with that i think i may have messed up.  I didn't pay attention to the fact that i'm actually using 2 different date columns in my query.  They are closely worded so that was my mistake.  When i change the dates to the same columns it looks much better, so thank you everyone, i think it was just a case of OE(operator error) ! Thank you !